# How to set up automatic connection to sites using wget

Tags: wget

Hello I would like to ask if it can not connect automatically to the site at 09:00 AM using wget
It would be nice if I did not have to open the page manually for points each day.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can schedule an cron job

then use below commands

`$ crontab -e
$ 00 09 * * * /path/to/script.sh`

more description on
[here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

if you are on windows then you can use task scheduler inbuilt given in windows